# problem with naming shape in vba excel when i want to use for i loop

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, naming

as you can see in the code i want to  create 2 shapes and group them together and do it  10 times with "for loop" for naming the shapes, but there is a problem with array() which doesn't accept variant and it will stop at 1st loop

```
Sub DRAWSHAPEs()
   myDocument = Worksheets(3)
   For i = 1 To 10
     For j = 11 To 20
   With myDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 100, 150, 50, 70)
   .Name = i
   .Line.Weight = 4
   .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
   .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
   .IncrementRotation 0
    With myDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 104, 145, 42, 78)
   .Name = j
   .Line.Weight = 4
   .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
   .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
   .IncrementRotation 0
    With myDocument.Shapes.Range(**Array(i, j))**.Group
    End With
    End With
    End With
     Next j
    Next i
    End Sub
```

run time error 1004 
 application defined or object defined

Answer (score 0):

Per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.range), `Shapes.Range` takes an `Index` parameter (emphasis mine):

> The individual shapes to be included in the range. Can be an integer that specifies the index number of the shape, a string that specifies the name of the shape, **or an array that contains either integers or strings**.

If you mean to give it *names*, then you need to give it an array of **strings**, not integers; an array of integers would be taken as *index numbers*, not shape names. `Array()` has no problem accepting variants.

Try explicitly converting the integers to strings:

```
With myDocument.Shapes.Range(Array(CStr(i), CStr(j))).Group
```

If that doesn't work, consider using strings that don't look like numbers when naming the shapes:

```
   .Name = "Shape" & i

   ...

   .Name = "Shape" & j
```

And then...

```
With myDocument.Shapes.Range(Array("Shape" & i, "Shape" & j)).Group
```

Works fine here.